# Setup is not adding row to table

Tags: magento2, installation

I want to add an `email` row to `reviews_details`.

In my Setup-folder is `install-1.0.0.php`:

```
<?php

namespace MS\RealReviews\Setup;


use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
      {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        $eavTable = $installer->getTable('review_detail');

        $columns = [
            'email' => [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                128,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' => 'User E-Mail Address',
            ],

        ];

        $connection = $installer->getConnection();
        foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
            $connection->addColumn($eavTable, $name, $definition);
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }

}
```

My `module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MS_RealReviews" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

Overview of table after `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`:
[image]

Comment: install-1.0.0.php - is it filename for class InstallData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Move your code from:

   ```
   MS\RealReviews\Setup\InstallData.php
   ```

   to:

   ```
   MS\RealReviews\Setup\InstallSchema.php
   ```

   ---

   ```
   class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
   {

       public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
       { 
           // your code goes here 
       }
   }
   ```
2. Check that your extension was enabled (I suppose, that *MS_RealReviews* is your extension name):

   ```
   php bin/magento module:status
   ```

   if not, run:

   ```
   php bin/magento module:enable MS_RealReviews
   ```
3. Delete from `module_setup` table your module for reinstall:

   ```
   DELETE FROM `setup_module` WHERE `setup_module`.`module` = 'MS_RealReviews'
   ```
4. Add some debug code in the `InstallSchema::install()`.
5. Reinstall:

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
   ```

Comment: Can you elaborate the 4th point? How to do that?

Comment: Temporarily add еру code:  exit('my install is works');   - for be sure that your installer execute.